# Compiling libmms under OS X

Tags: c, macos, static-libraries, mms

I'm having trouble with some very basic static library linking in C. The library is libMMS 0.6.2, and the program is as simple as I could make it. libmms.a and test.c are in the same folder, with the header files under ./libmms. The compiler is llvm-gcc-4.2 under OS X Lion.

compiling libmms:

```
CFLAGS="-march=x86_64" ./configure
make
```

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libmms/mms.h"

int main(void)
{
    mms_t *mms = mms_connect(NULL, NULL, "mms://some.url.com", 128*1024);
    return 0;
}
```

compiling program:

```
gcc -o test test.c libmms.a
```

which gives me a long list of undefined symbols

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_libiconv", referenced from:
      _string_utf16 in libmms.a(mms.o)
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
      _mms_connect in libmms.a(mms.o)
  "_libiconv_close", referenced from:
      _mms_connect in libmms.a(mms.o)
  "_g_strdup", referenced from:
      _split_user_passwd in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_new in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_new_fields in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_new_fields_all in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_clone in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_set_scheme in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_set_userinfo in libmms.a(uri.o)
      ...
  "_g_free", referenced from:
      _split_user_passwd in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_new in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_delete in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _field_escape in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_set_scheme in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_set_userinfo in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_set_hostname in libmms.a(uri.o)
      ...
  "_g_return_if_fail_warning", referenced from:
      _gnet_uri_new in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_clone in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_equal in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_hash in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_escape in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_unescape in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_get_string in libmms.a(uri.o)
      ...
  "_g_malloc0_n", referenced from:
      _gnet_uri_new in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_new_fields in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_new_fields_all in libmms.a(uri.o)
      _gnet_uri_clone in libmms.a(uri.o)
  "_g_strndup", referenced from:
      _gnet_uri_new in libmms.a(uri.o)
  "_g_str_hash", referenced from:
      _gnet_uri_hash in libmms.a(uri.o)
  "_g_malloc", referenced from:
      _field_escape in libmms.a(uri.o)
  "_g_string_sized_new", referenced from:
      _gnet_uri_get_string in libmms.a(uri.o)
  "_g_string_append_printf", referenced from:
      _gnet_uri_get_string in libmms.a(uri.o)
  "_g_string_append", referenced from:
      _gnet_uri_get_string in libmms.a(uri.o)
  "_g_string_free", referenced from:
      _gnet_uri_get_string in libmms.a(uri.o)
  "_g_string_insert_c", referenced from:
      _g_string_append_c_inline in libmms.a(uri.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: You shouldn't have to specify the -march option at all. The llvm-gcc will by default build for 64bit architecture.

Comment: @cli_hit I tried without that option at first, but same problem

Comment: @trojanfoe Updated with the full error message

Comment: Looks like libiconv is missing and I don't know about the `g_*` symbols; are they part if libmms.a?  In other words there are other libraries you need to link with.  Have you checked the docs?

Comment: Looks like you need to link `libiconv` and probably `glib` as well.

Comment: I've just downloaded the sources and I didn't see any information about what other libraries are needed; crap docs.  You need libiconv.a for sure, but the `g_*` symbols look to be part of gnome?  That can't be right.

Comment: @trojanfoe: The `g_*` functions are indeed part of Glib, which is part of the GNOME project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `libmms` depends on both `libiconv` and `glib`, so you'll need to link those as well.